# Access Rails Development Server From A Different Computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, webrick

I'm using webrick to develop my rails app on Mac OS X Lion.  I'm trying to access the site from another computer (for testing).  The internal IP of my computer is 10.1.10.100.

Accessing `10.1.10.100` displays the page served by the apache server running on my computer.

Accessing `10.1.10.100:3000` times out, both from my computer and from another computer on the same network.  I can ping `10.1.10.100`.  From my computer, `loaclhost:3000` displays the app.

Is there are firewall I need to open up on Mac OS X or some other setting that needs to be applied?

Thanks

Comment: Another [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4928680/2767755)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

While starting the webrick server specify the IP on which your rails application will run (10.1.10.100 in your case) using -b option, it binds Rails to the specified IP.

```
rails server -b 10.1.10.100 -p 3000
```

Comment: Replace "rails server" with "ruby script/server" in case you are using rails 2.

Comment: Strangely, this worked with thin too, even though when the port wasn't explicitly set, `netstat` showed it listening on all interfaces ("*") and `nmap` showed it open, but it didn't respond.

Comment: @Akarsh this worked for me, thanks! BTW, I've been using rails s for development purposes for some time and I was always able to access my app within the same network using machine IP. Do you know why I need this now? Maybe some different machine config?

Comment: Instead of typing the IP each time, you can enter something like this: `rails s -b $(ipconfig getifaddr en0)` (just check if `en0` is actually your interface name, I based my comment on this: http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/21/find-ip-address-mac/).