# How to start rails server on some other port?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to start rails sever on port other that 3000 so that I can run two applications simultaneously on my machine. One is running on server using port 3000 and 2nd with new port.

Comment: rails s -p <your-desired-port-number>

Comment: `rails s -p your_port_number`

Comment: `rails server --help`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running multiple instances of Rails Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928680/running-multiple-instances-of-rails-server)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the -p option:

```
rails server -p 3001
```

Answer (score 10):

```
rails s -p <port_number>
```